# wpf datagrid expander show x items

Tags: wpf, datagrid, expander, groupstyle

I have an `Expander` in my `DataGrid`, but I want to only show TWO items, and then when user click on expand, show remaining items.

How can that be done ?

```
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle AlternationCount="7" >
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Expander IsExpanded="False" Background="{Binding XPath=recipient_color}">                                            
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding}">
                                    </Label>                                                
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <Expander.Content>
                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                </Expander.Content>
                            </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it that would require more fiddling around with the xaml though, would be to modify the Expander control template. In the control template on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753296%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), you can see that the grid row that's named `ContentRow`. The height of that row starts at 0, then a trigger on the `IsExpanded` property expands it to its desired height. If you set the default `ContentRow` height to something like 50 (or whatever height is needed to show the number of items you want), it will show the top part of the group's items when the Expander is collapsed.

You can read up more on how to modify ControlTemplates [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: can you give an example how to implement  ?

Comment: @keno Basically all you need to do is copy all of the xaml from the link I gave you (including the resources at the bottom) and dump it in your DataGrid.Resources. Then change the height of ContentRow from 0 to whatever. The problem is the template there may not match your current theme and it can be hard to find the correct starting template. But its worth a try.

Comment: Hahahahaha IT WORKED !!!! :D it is indeed not the same template as the original (back color of header is blue/purple etc). But I'll change that mannualy ;) Thanks !

Comment: Can I put that template into another file ?

Comment: Yeah, it should work to move it all to an empty ResourceDictionary file. Then add that to the grid resources using the MergedDictionaries collection.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your expander's header, add a control of your choice that is able to show the 2 first items of your list.
2. Bind the visibility of the above control to the "IsExpanded" proprty of the expander, so that the control is hidden when the expander is expanded (use IValueConverter)
3. Build the content of your expander to show all of the items.

This way, when the expander is not expanded, it will show the 2 items in the header (style this to your liking). When the user expands, the 2 items disappear, the expander is expanded and the whole list is shown again.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for that ! Great idea ;) but howto select first items from my xml data... I can set <ItemsPresenter/> into a stackpanel into my header, but that show all the items... and manually changing the height isn't a solution either because the data into the header is loading anyway and no good :-)

Comment: I don't know how your code is setup, but you could've created a different binding to a collection of 2 items that you manage in code behind - or it's probably doable via an IValueConverter too (take a collection as input, and output only the first 2 items if they exist). But I'm glad you found a solution anyway :)